# I can't change the date format with python datetime

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, type-conversion

I have a dataframe that contains a column in date values ​​in string mode. I want to convert it to a datetime but I can't do it at all.

I have first tried to get the datetime function to autodetect it, but it can't. I have also tried to do it manually but I did not reach the solution either.
The date format is '1 Ago 2020', the month is in Spanish format and at the same time, as you can see, it does not contain the double 0 in the days until 9.

I have used different codes but here I show an example of some.

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
dfweight = pd.read_csv('data_weight.csv') 
pd.to_datetime(dfweight['Fecha'], format='%d %b, %Y')
```

Where he threw: ValueError: time data ' 12 May 2020' does not match format '%d %b, %Y' (match)

I also tried adding # (% # d) so it doesn't show 0 through 9 as I read in some comments but it shows the following error.

ValueError: '#' is a bad directive in format '% # d% b,% Y'

If someone can help me I thank you in advance because I am blocked.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Spanish format, you'll need to set a Spanish `locale`.

1. in your shell, run `locale-gen`.  this ensures you'll have the localisation files necessary.

```sh
  >> sudo locale-gen es_ES.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  es_ES.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

2. in python, first set the locale.  then call something like `datetime.datetime.strptime`.  If you pass the right string (like `"%d %b %Y"`) for your [date format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) , it shouldn't matter about the 0's.

```s
  >> python3
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> import datetime
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8')
'es_ES.UTF-8'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("1 Ago 2020", "%d %b %Y")
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("09 Ago 2020", "%d %b %Y")
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 9, 0, 0)
```